# HKWorkoutSession isn't keeping app at front of Apple Watch

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit, watchos-2

It has been stated that an app running a HKWorkoutSession will have special privileges over other watchOS 2 apps, so when a user looks at their Apple Watch, it will go to the view showing running a workout rather than the watch face.

Currently, on both my device and simulator, this is not the case. If I start a HKWorkoutSession and then leave for 5 minutes and then interact with either the Apple Watch, or the Watch Simulator, it presents the watch face.

If I then open my app, it appears to have been frozen, rather than terminated (which is what I imagine happens to other apps). As the UI will update when I need receive a response in my query.updateHandler. Also if I set it to provide haptic feedback every time my query.updateHandler receives a new HKQuantitySample it will do so, so the app must be running in the background in some form.

Has anyone else noticed this behaviour, and am I doing anything wrong, or expecting something I shouldn't?

Here is how I start my HKWorkoutSession:

```
    self.workoutSession = HKWorkoutSession(activityType: HKWorkoutActivityType.Other, locationType: HKWorkoutSessionLocationType.Indoor)

        self.healthStore.startWorkoutSession(self.workoutSession) {
            success, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("startWorkoutSession \(error)\n")
                self.printLabel.setText("startWorkoutSession \(error)")
                self.printLabel.setTextColor(UIColor.redColor())
            }
```

Comment: After further investigation I've decided that my code is continuing to run in the background, and that I should have code to update the UI on willActivate, rather than waiting for a new query. I'll keep this open a bit longer because there isn't a definite answer on why the app doesn't remain in the foreground.

Comment: Have you tried to change the setting on the AppleWatch that opens last activity on wrist raise? Within the AppleWatch app on IOS General. IF this is essential for your users you could prompt them to change the setting

Comment: Yeah thats a decent idea if this "bug" ends up become the default behaviour. Ideally though I don't want to force the user to change their Apple Watch "workflow" just for my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're seeing that too, for the moment we've made sure 'opens last activity' is configured.

When the UI is active we start a dispatch_timer to request and process data in 1 second intervals.

Make sure you do any significant processing using the NSUserProcessInfo method though and pause the dispatch_timers whenever you are no longer active. You'll get crashes otherwise.

Comment: What is NSUserProcessInfo? When searching for it I only find NSProcessInfo & that seems OS X only. I am getting crashes pretty quickly. I need to check if I should send a haptic vibration after a sample is returned, and that needs to happen when the UI isn't active.

Comment: Interestingly when I have 'opens last activity' configured I get far less heart rate data, but no crashes.

Comment: Sorry, I was doing that from memory, it's actually:  `NSProcessInfo.processInfo().performExpiringActivityWithReason`. It gives a block which will perform expiring tasks post screen going inactive. Re: heart rate I believe it's in the beta release notes that it's currently not measuring heart rate whilst the screen is inactive. It's a known bug.

Comment: When I start a workout session I get heart rate nicely. But when the screen locks (turns black) the heart rate samples stop. And after a while the sensor stops as well (not green anymore). You know what this is about?