# How to make HKworkoutsession always an active workout session

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I'm working on apple watch app and I'm using HKworkoutsession to access heart rate data sample.

In the newest watchos2 beta3 release bug "During an active workout session, new heart rate samples are not generated when the screen is off." is fixed.

My question is how could I set my HKworkoutsession always as an "active work out session" thus I could keep getting heart rate sample as I need.

Thanks
Ryan

Comment: To be more specific, when I tilt my watch, screen will turn off, program get hanged. When I tilt back, screen turns on, HKworkout session at this timing point will first switch to ".Ended" and then switch to ".Running".  How to prevent this happening and keep the session always ".Running"

Comment: Sounds like a HealthKit bug that you should report to Apple.

Comment: @user3781258 Any progress on this matter?

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224611/hkworkoutsession-isnt-keeping-app-at-front-of-apple-watch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code following is how to start or stop workout session.

```
let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
healthStore.startWorkoutSession(workoutSession) {
  (result: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
}

healthStore.stopWorkoutSession(workoutSession) {
  (result: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
}
```

There is HKWorkoutSessionDelegate which notifies its session state.

```
protocol HKWorkoutSessionDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {

func workoutSession(workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession,
  didChangeToState toState: HKWorkoutSessionState,
  fromState: HKWorkoutSessionState, date: NSDate)

func workoutSession(workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession,
  didFailWithError error: NSError)
}
```

[Edited] 2015/08/31

ObjC version

```
HKWorkoutSession *workoutSession = [[HKWorkoutSession alloc] initWithActivityType:HKWorkoutActivityTypeRunning locationType:HKWorkoutSessionLocationTypeOutdoor];
workoutSession.delegate = self;

HKHealthStore *healthStore = [HKHealthStore new];
[healthStore startWorkoutSession:workoutSession];

[healthStore stopWorkoutSession:workoutSession];
```

HKWrokoutSessionDelegate

```
- (void)workoutSession:(HKWorkoutSession *)workoutSession
  didChangeToState:(HKWorkoutSessionState)toState
         fromState:(HKWorkoutSessionState)fromState
              date:(NSDate *)date;

- (void)workoutSession:(HKWorkoutSession *)workoutSession didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Caution: There is a change of method name with the latest version, watch OS 2 beta 5.

**stopWorkoutSession has changed to endWorkoutSession.**

Comment: Can you please translate your example to Objective C?

Comment: I edited with Objective-C codes. Please take a look!

Comment: I have code similar to this and still see the behavior described in the question.

Comment: First of all, it doesn't work on iPhone simulator. Secondly, it should be granted to access HealthKit on a containing iOS app. Thirdly, you should use HKAnchoredObjectQuery to receive updates of heart rate data.